# Average for year if some stores stop selling product

Tags: mean, finance

I am trying to calculate yearly sales averages per product across a number of stores.  The average should only include those stores which carry a product.  So if I have stores A, B, and C and products X, Y, and Z, I want the average sales of products X, Y, and Z across all 3 stores, but if store C does not carry product X, store C should not be included in the average for product X.

This is all simple but what if store C carried product X at the beginning of the year but stopped selling it half way through the year?  The product X sales for store C should be incorporated in the average for the duration in which they sold the product but the rest of the year during which they stopped selling the product would throw off the average.  So how would the average sales for the year of product X be represented?

Comment: What units would you like your answer to be in? That will help. I think you could scale them all to be the same.

Comment: You can calculate the daily averages of every store and then multiply them by number of days in a year.

Comment: @dankernler dollar amounts for total sales of the product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just scale them all to the same time range. If the first had \$3,000 in only 3 months, just scale that to \$1,000 per month. If you do the same for the ones that had it for sale for the entire year, you'd have them all with a comparable scale.

I would probably still mention that it wasn't for a full year, though. Something like "Store A averaged sales of \$1,000 per month, though the item was only sold from October through December."

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  I was hoping for a special stats trick that would give me the yearly value consistent with our other reports but this calculation makes sense with the data and should work.

Comment: You can make it yearly if you want. Just scale your total for that store to an annual amount. It's a little misleading, though, to talk about $x/year, when it was only on sale for a few months.